# Join/Merge two or more pandas dataframes which have 4 columns in common

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I know this question might seem repetitive at first, but the truth is that it is not, since I cannot find another answer or similar question whose solution works for me.

I am working with `pandas` dataframes, using `Python` language.

Suppose we have 3 datasets, ***A*** ***B*** and ***C***.

1. ***B*** and ***C*** are sub-datasets of ***A*** (dataframe ***A*** was splitted in two according to a binary column value)
2. The datasets are of different lenghts (***A*** is the biggest, ***B*** and ***C*** are smaller since they are sub-datasets of ***A***)
3. Each dataset has 5 columns: ***a***, ***b***, ***c***, ***d*** and ***e*** (they have the same column names)
4. Columns ***a***, ***b***, ***c*** and ***d*** (taken all together) do not have any repetitions (they could be a composed key of a database)
5. Column ***e*** is different for each dataset
6. Each dataset has a different index from the others (they were NOT generated using pandas.loc, I am dealing with them "already built and taken from outside python")

My question is: **how can I put all these together without losing any row and by pairing them correcty without using the index?**

Here's an example:

```
* Content of A *:
a   b   c   d   e
"x" "y" 0   1   0.99        # 0
"x" "y" 1   1   0.43        # 1
"x" "z" 0   0   0.90        # 2
"y" "z" 0   1   0.11        # 3
"x" "z" 0   1   0.78        # 4

* Content of B *:
a   b   c   d   e
"x" "y" 0   1   0.12        # 0 of dataframe A
"x" "z" 0   0   0.01        # 2 of dataframe A
"y" "z" 0   1   0.45        # 3 of dataframe A

* Content of C *:
a   b   c   d   e
"x" "y" 1   1   0.06        # 1 of dataframe A
"x" "z" 0   0   0.65        # 2 of dataframe A
"x" "z" 0   1   0.20        # 4 of dataframe A
```

I would like to obtain this output:

```
* Content of new_df *:
a   b   c   d   e_A   e_B   e_C
"x" "y" 0   1   0.99  0.12  NaN
"x" "y" 1   1   0.43  NaN   0.06
"x" "z" 0   0   0.90  0.01  0.65
"y" "z" 0   1   0.11  0.45  NaN
"x" "z" 0   1   0.78  NaN   0.20
```

My first trial for the code was the following line, but it deleted the rows which did not have all the three values (instead, I need to insert NaN).

```
new_df1 = pd.merge(A, B, how='left', left_on=["a", "b", "c", "d"]
new_df2 = pd.merge(new_df1, C, how='left', left_on=["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

How can I achieve my objective of getting a full dataset made of all columns (5) and all rows (***A*** contains the maximum amount of rows)?

reproducible input:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'x'],
                  'b': ['y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z'],
                  'c': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                  'd': [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                  'e': [0.99, 0.43, 0.9, 0.11, 0.78]})

B = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['x', 'x', 'y'],
                  'b': ['y', 'z', 'z'],
                  'c': [0, 0, 0],
                  'd': [1, 0, 1],
                  'e': [0.12, 0.01, 0.45]})

C = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['x', 'x', 'x'],
                  'b': ['y', 'z', 'z'],
                  'c': [1, 0, 0],
                  'd': [1, 0, 1],
                  'e': [0.06, 0.65, 0.2]})
```

Comment: Can you provide your dataframes as DataFrame constructors?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand what you mean @mozway. Can you explain me what should I add to my question please?

Comment: code like `dfA = pd.DataFrame(...)` so that one can just copy/paste it to have the objects

Comment: I created them here while writing the question, let me try to copy them on python...

Comment: Works fine for me (except the suffixes)

Comment: I added the reproducible input ;)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me.

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
b = pd.read_csv('b.csv')
c = pd.read_csv('c.csv')

e = a.merge(b, how='left', left_on=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], right_on=['a','b','c', 'd'], suffixes=['_A', '_B'])
e = e.merge(c, how='left', left_on=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], right_on=['a','b','c', 'd'])

e = e.rename(columns={'e': 'e_C'})

print(e.head())
```

A bit explanation, `pd.DataFrame.merge()` currently supports explicitly state the joining columns [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). So using that we can merge it.

And suffix parameter lets you rename the overlapping columns like by adding provided suffix for both df `(left_df_suffix, right_df_suffix)`.

Rest is as you have tried. I renamed the `e` column of `c.csv` (or DF) after merging. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I am trying to make it work but it returns only row `2  x  z  0  0  0.90  0.01  0.65`. Upgrading to the latest version of pandas did not help. I upvoted you anyways

Comment: @hellomynameisA hi! can you check the attached csv files I used for the solution.. Maybe that can help you figure out why its not working for you? https://gist.github.com/mehedi-shafi/b0e8e78ba103f6b72e78eb32386f003b

Comment: Great idea! This way it works fine... Maybe that's a memory shortage problem with my (very) big datasets... I'll try to work on the datasets somehow, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Combine the keys which are common in a string as shown in the code below.

```py
    A['pKey'] = A.apply(lambda row: row['a'] + "_" + row['b'] + "_" + str(row['c']) + "_" + str(row['d']), axis=1)
    B['pKey'] = B.apply(lambda row: row['a'] + "_" + row['b'] + "_" + str(row['c']) + "_" + str(row['d']), axis=1)
    C['pKey'] = C.apply(lambda row: row['a'] + "_" + row['b'] + "_" + str(row['c']) + "_" + str(row['d']), axis=1)
```

Then combine the tables using this new column:

```
merge_ab = A.merge(B, on='pKey', how='left', suffixes=('_A', '_B'))
merge_abc = merge_ab.merge(C, on='pKey', how='left', suffixes=('', '_C'))
```

Now drop useless columns.

```
    a   b   c   d   e_A     e_B     e_C
0   x   y   0   1   0.99    0.12    NaN
1   x   y   1   1   0.43    NaN     0.06
2   x   z   0   0   0.93    0.01    0.65
3   y   z   0   1   0.11    0.45    NaN
4   x   z   0   1   0.78    NaN     0.20
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I am trying to make it work but it returns only row `2  x  z  0  0  0.90  0.01  0.65`. Upgrading to the latest version of pandas did not help. I upvoted you anyways

Comment: Hi, thank you for the upvote. Here's the colab notebook link for my answer. Hope this helps.    

Link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vh_lTkElpaVa_avfi_JgFqkc3UAZU7mi?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to hold your dataframes and use `functools.reduce`:

```
dfs = {'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C}

from functools import reduce

out= reduce(lambda a, b: a.merge(b, how='left', on=["a", "b", "c", "d"]),
            [d.rename(columns={'e': f'e_{k}'}) for k,d in dfs.items()])
```

Or, if you have non-merge columns other than "e":

```
dfs = {'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C}

from functools import reduce

out = (reduce(lambda a, b: a.join(b, how='left'),
              [d.set_index(["a", "b", "c", "d"]).add_suffix(f'_{k}') 
               for k,d in dfs.items()])
       .reset_index()
      )
```

output:

```
   a  b  c  d   e_A   e_B   e_C
0  x  y  0  1  0.99  0.12   NaN
1  x  y  1  1  0.43   NaN  0.06
2  x  z  0  0  0.90  0.01  0.65
3  y  z  0  1  0.11  0.45   NaN
4  x  z  0  1  0.78   NaN  0.20
```

Comment: I'm super sorry to write this, but for some reason it does not work on my machine. I copied-pasted your code and just changed the column names to my real column names and it only adds rows which have all three values. I have pandas 1.3.4, do you think it is too old?

Comment: what means "does not work"? error message (which one)? incorrect output (how)?

Comment: It returns a dataframe which has only rows which do not have NaN

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Example from above:    only row  
`2  x  z  0  0  0.90  0.01  0.65`

Comment: so, to be clear, if you copy the A/B/C constructors from the question and run my solution, this is what you get?

Comment: Exactly, I get only the row which has all values

Comment: I tried the other answers as well, I think the problem is in my machine because none of the answers give all the 5 rows

Comment: well, then yes try to upgrade, this is strange…

Comment: Upgrading did not work... thank you anyways, I upvote your answer

Comment: @hellomynameisA I'm very sorry, then restart a fresh interpreter/notebook and try again, I'm sure this should work